# How do I check if multple variables in a script are true?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that during the script, evaluates a variable and if it passes one of the tests, a variable inside the if/else statement gets set to true.

```
    if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
        conditions_met += 1
    else:
        password_needs_uppercase = True

    if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
        conditions_met += 1
    else:
        password_needs_lowercase = True

    if re.search('\d', password):
        conditions_met += 1
    else:
        password_needs_number = True
```

How can I check if one of the variables (password_needs_uppercase, password_needs_lowercase, and password_needs_number) are True?

Comment: As written, you can check if `conditions_met` is less than the maximum possible value. You don't even need to set the individual `password_needs_*` variables.

Comment: At the end of the script, if the password didn't pass certain tests (if/else statements), I want to tell them how they can improve it. (e.g. `if password_too_short: print('-try using more characters.')`

Comment: See my answer. You can restructure the `if` statement if you don't want to stop checking after the first error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [any()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any((password_needs_uppercase, password_needs_lowercase, 
password_needs_number)):
```

Comment: Thanks, I googled the issue, but the answers that I got were not working. I'll mark your answer as accepted when I can.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need regex at all

```
password_needs_uppercase, password_needs_lowercase, password_needs_number = True, True, True
password = "Welcome123"
for char in password:
    if char.isupper(): password_needs_uppercase = False
    elif char.islower(): password_needs_lowercase = False
    elif char.isdigit(): password_needs_number = False

if any((password_needs_number, password_needs_lowercase, password_needs_uppercase)):
    print "password is not valid"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if the number of passed searches is less than the maximum possible.

```
if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
    conditions_met += 1

if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
    conditions_met += 1

if re.search('\d', password):
    conditions_met += 1

if conditions_met < 3:
    handle_bad_password()
```

If you need specific handling for each failed case, it's better to do it immediately, rather than use hard-coded variable names that you check later.

```
if not re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
    handle_missing_uppercase()
elif not re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
    handle_missing_lowercase()
elif re.search('\d', password):
    handle_missing_numbers()
else:
    handle_acceptible_password()
```